# My deployment scripts are utilizing all the ram and taking forever

Tags: cron, root, ram, cpu, php7

Even if I increase the ram it will end up just using it up and bogging down. I'm not sure if this is riding the gray line of what should be in magento stack exchange vs ask ubuntu.

Why are these processes taking so long?

```
.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.5 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  7872472 total,  6474564 free,   779124 used,   618784 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8388604 total,  8388604 free,        0 used.  6777260 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 1363 root      20   0 4452608 178016  20008 S   1.0  2.3   0:12.48 java -jar /opt/username.jar -disableSslVerification -master https://jenkins-sand.mybox.com/ -username **** -password **** -labels sand admin magento          
 2636 www-data  20   0  368200  87020  22260 R  30.4  1.1   0:00.31 /usr/bin/php7.1 /var/www/code/mybox.com/releases/20180607064456/bin/magento cron:run --group=index --bootstrap=standaloneProcessStarted=1                                                           
 2638 www-data  20   0  368196  86964  22212 R  33.3  1.1   0:00.34 /usr/bin/php7.1 /var/www/code/mybox.com/releases/20180607064456/bin/magento cron:run --group=staging --bootstrap=standaloneProcessStarted=1                                                         
 2644 www-data  20   0  368196  86960  22208 R  32.4  1.1   0:00.33 /usr/bin/php7.1 /var/www/code/mybox.com/releases/20180607064456/bin/magento cron:run --group=ddg_automation --bootstrap=standaloneProcessStarted=1                                                  
 2642 www-data  20   0  368408  86876  21984 R  38.2  1.1   0:00.39 /usr/bin/php7.1 /var/www/code/mybox.com/releases/20180607064456/bin/magento cron:run --group=consumers --bootstrap=standaloneProcessStarted=1                                                       
 2640 www-data  20   0  367424  86276  22012 R  25.5  1.1   0:00.26 /usr/bin/php7.1 /var/www/code/mybox.com/releases/20180607064456/bin/magento cron:run --group=catalog_event --bootstrap=standaloneProcessStarted=1                                                   
 2383 root      20   0  457208  64840  37080 S   0.0  0.8   0:00.28 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://                                                                                                                                                                                  
 2088 www-data  20   0  461188  62800  47200 S   0.0  0.8   0:00.66 php-fpm: pool www                                                                                                                                                                                          
 2084 root      20   0  451052  47712  40120 S   0.0  0.6   0:00.07 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf)                                                                                                                                                    
 2092 www-data  20   0  461088  44652  29052 S   3.9  0.6   0:00.25 php-fpm: pool www                                                                                                                                                                                          
 2091 www-data  20   0  461088  44648  29052 S   0.0  0.6   0:00.23 php-fpm: pool www                                                                                                                                                                                          
 2089 www-data  20   0  461088  44644  29048 S   0.0  0.6   0:00.25 php-fpm: pool www                                                                                                                                                                                          
 2090 www-data  20   0  461088  44644  29048 S   0.0  0.6   0:00.24 php-fpm: pool www
```

I do believe it has something to do with the `group=catalog_event --bootstrap=standaloneProcessStarted=1` and all the bootstrap stand alone processes before this one.

Does anything stand out as a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes man. It's a well-known issue in Magento 2. See the ticket [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11002).

And a workaround (extension) is available [here](https://github.com/magemojo/m2-ce-cron).